# Can someone tell me why this javascript function does not execute?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is a very simple solution. I have made this javacript function that tests whether there is a certain css style on a div and then moves around another div. However, it does not work and I have no idea why.

JavaScript:

```
function sale() {
    var style = document.getElementsByClassName("product-single__price--wrapper").getAttribute("style");
    if (style !="display: none;") {
        document.getElementByClassName("product-single__description").style.marginTop = "70px !important";
    }
}
window.onload = sale;
```

Comment: *"Can someone tell me why this javascript function does not execute?"* You don't seem to be calling the function anywhere? But even if you did `document.getElementById("ProductPrice").style.margin-top = ...` is an error. You cannot access a property with dot notation if it contains a `-`.

Comment: because there's no such thing as `style.margin-top`, unless you're trying to subtract a variable named `top` from `style.margin`. I think you want `.style.marginTop`.

Comment: Does this function not check the css style at all times? If not how can I get it to do so? @FelixKling

Comment: My point is that your example is incomplete. While the code will throw an error, you are not showing whether `sale` is called at all.  Please read [mcve] and provide a running example the reproduces the issue. Look at your console for errors (there are more problems with your code, e.g. `getElementsByClassName` returns a **list** elements, not a single elements).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that could be true, however it still did not solve the problem. Maybe the issue is that the function isn't being called as someone else said.

Comment: In javascript, the names of all css properties that contain a dash, will get converted in a manner so that the character following the dash will be capitalized and the dash gets removed. `margin-top` becomes `style.marginTop`, `border-spacing` becomes `style.borderSpacing`

Comment: @SpencerM. It doesn't look like you're actually calling the code, that's why it's not hitting. Can you explain when you want it to be called?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I just thought that if I don't set the function to run after a certain event then it would run at all times. How can I make it run that way?

Comment: @SpencerM. Dude... slow down. When do you want that specific function called?

Comment: @SpencerM. No. Functions don't just run all the time if you don't call it, lol.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet I want it to call that function essentially "at all times". For example, when the page loads but also if the user interacts with the page at all while on that page.

Comment: *facepalm* @SpencerM. What? When do you want it called? All the time?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Yes all the time

Comment: *Why* do you want it to run "all the time"? What are you actually trying to do? Because I can guarantee you that, whatever it is, there's a much better solution than calling the same function every second or so.

Comment: @FelixKling does the edited version of the function make sense now? I have never used setInterval before

Comment: @Kevin I have a shopify website and when the product is on sale and shows the sale price, an unwanted space appears below the price and above the product description. So, I would like to change the top margin of the product description when the sale price style does not equal "display: none;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't ever suggest doing this, but if you want to call that function all the time, you need to put it into a setInterval with the milliseconds you want it to get called.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        sale();
    }, 1000);
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(sale, 1000);
});
```

This will get called every second. Again, horrible horrible horrible practice. But, this will do what you want. If you want it called sooner, then change the milliseconds accordingly (1000 milliseconds = 1 second).

Comment: if I include this after the function it will run it all the time?

Comment: include it in `document.ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Or just `setInterval(sale, 1000)`. No need to create a new function just to call a function.